# Windows 8 app hooks

Tags: c#, hook, windows-store-apps

Is there a mechanism for working with WebViews and easily get the JavaScript hooks to callback to C# events (like on iOS)?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In a C# app you're pretty limited in what you can do from a `WebView`:

- You can raise [`ScriptNotify`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/windows.ui.xaml.controls.webview.scriptnotify) event and pass a value to the app by calling `window.external.notify` in Javascript.
- To communicate in the opposite direction you can call [`InvokeScript`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/xaml/windows.ui.xaml.controls.webview.invokescript.aspx) from your app code.

If that's not enough for your needs you should take a look at developing a Windows Store app in HTML and Javascript. In this case you don't need to use a `WebView` - your app pages are HTML and your app code is Javascript. You can use any WinRT APIs and consume third party WinRT components which can be written in C#.